# ios mpvolumeview route button not vertically centered on ios 7.1 update

Tags: ios, uislider, mpvolumeview

i am making an app that play audio files. i am showing mpvolumeview which is working fine.
but the problem is after i updated ios 7.1 .
the route button gone down . see attached image
[image]

dont know what happened other simple ui slider are ok nothing wrong with them..
but mpvolumeslider has this issue came after ios 7.1 .

i am using this code to add a volumeslider..

```
*MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:myView.bounds] ;
 [myView addSubview:volumeView];*
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and it turned out to be because after the MPVolumeView was created, the code was looking through MPVolumeView's subviews to find a UISlider, and adjusting the `minimum/maxmimumTrackTintColor`.

To fix it, I just changed that to this code:

```
[volumeView setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding the diabled state to the set min and max slider image:

```
[volumeView setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"minImg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateDisabled];

[volumeView setMaximumVolumeSliderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maxImg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateDisabled];
```